# Табуляция и пробел

Tags: java

Что такое табуляция? Как ее описать в джава коде и почему некоторые люди пишут, что всегда лучше использовать табуляцию?

Comment: что то мне подсказывает, что Вы слышали дискуссию на тему, что лучше использовать для форматирования кода - пробелы или табуляцию.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Табуляция - это непечатаемый (управляющий) символ, в общем случае вводится по нажатию на клавишу Tab на клавиатуре.

Хорошей практикой является выделение логических блоков в коде (циклов, условий, классов и методов) с помощью табуляции или нескольких (обычно - четырёх) пробелов. Это служит для удобочитаемости кода и ускоряет его восприятие.

Сравните варианты с табуляцией и без:

*С табуляцией:*

```
package helloworld;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, world!");
    }
}
```

*Без табуляции:*

```
package helloworld;
public class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("Hello, world!");
}
}
```